# NVMe SSD suddenly went impractically slow (both read and write)

Tags: linux, ssd, performance, nvme

**Update 1**: I rebooted this server into another Ubuntu (also 20.04 LTS) installed on the HDD, and `hdparm -tT` shows a reasonable performance of over 1 GB/s. Now I'm inclined to believe it's a software issue - the SSD should be OK itself.

**Update 2**: Confusingly, `atop` shows no strange disk activity, yet the disk is still "very active". A lot of `z_wr_iss` threads show up randomly once in a while.

[image: atop]

---

That's an HP SSD EX920 1TB installed on a desktop computer running 24/7 as a personal server. It worked well for over a year and only last week, *suddenly*, processes started going D (uninterruptable sleep) randomly. This drive is only half full and regularly trimmed.

HDparm testing results are ridiculous (`/dev/nvme0` is the SSD in question, `/dev/sda` is another HDD) (**Clarify**: HDparm program is OK and not malfunctioning, the SSD itself has a wrong performance of only a few MB/s):

```
root@ubuntu:~# hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing cached reads:   15670 MB in  2.00 seconds = 7839.79 MB/sec
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 Timing buffered disk reads:   8 MB in  3.61 seconds =   2.22 MB/sec

root@ubuntu:~# hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   29014 MB in  2.00 seconds = 14525.03 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 454 MB in  3.01 seconds = 150.67 MB/sec
```

However, SMART information looks OK:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-56-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       HP SSD EX920 1TB
Serial Number:                      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Firmware Version:                   SVN139B
PCI Vendor ID:                      0x1dee
PCI Vendor Subsystem ID:            0x126f
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Mon Dec  7 13:54:15 2020 CST
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0016):   Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         64 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     70 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0450W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    2000
 4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4     6000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        54 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    31,682,199 [16.2 TB]
Data Units Written:                 50,028,403 [25.6 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 538,395,033
Host Write Commands:                1,279,795,487
Controller Busy Time:               20,480
Power Cycles:                       1,012
Power On Hours:                     7,879
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   40
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    7
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Thermal Temp. 1 Transition Count:   8
Thermal Temp. 2 Transition Count:   2
Thermal Temp. 1 Total Time:         1118
Thermal Temp. 2 Total Time:         214

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 256 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

Trying to access APM information (`hdparm -B`) on this NVMe SSD only gives "Inappropriate ioctl for device".

Additionally, I have **not** discovered any corrupt data (all intact), only unreasonably slow read/write speeds.

The drive has three partitions: an EFI System Partition (a few hundred MiB), an ext4 partition as root filesystem (128 GiB), and the rest goes to ZFS. Running `hdparm -tT` on individual partitions yields similar results (less than 10 MB/s read speed). All of these partitions are aligned to 1 MiB boundaries.

What should I do next to restore the "normal" speed of this SSD? Or should I get a replacement?

Comment: Are the speeds the same if you boot from a live USB version of Linux? What about putting the nvme in a USB3 enclosure and trying it on another system?

Comment: @Mokubai The speed is OK if I boot from a live ISO image (Debian or Ubuntu), but I don't have physical access right now (operating over IPMI).

Comment: That makes it sound like an operating system issue such as something thrashing the disk or a misconfiguration of some kind. Have you recently updated or changed configuration?

Comment: I routinely run `apt dist-upgrade` (this is an Ubuntu server) and I found [this question on AU](//askubuntu.com/q/1296497/612877). I'm currently trying to get an old kernel and packages back.

Comment: Can you see any odd disk activity using `atop`?

Comment: `atop` shows nothing suspicious - I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: Theres definitely something wrong, 6MB/s read *and* write is odd. Something doing thousands of tiny read and writes might be saturating the interface while using little bandwidth. In `atop` you can use shift-d to sort the process list by disk activity and just "d" will show *only* disk activity. Otherwise I'd be wondering about PCIe bandwidth, whether it has been starved of links by another device. `lspci -vv` should show `lnkSta` lines that tell you what the link is running at while `lspci -tv` may show you the bus layout and give hints that way.  Seems odd that other OSes are fine.

Comment: Your update 2 seems to suggest that it is something zfs related... https://www.google.com/search?q=z_wr_iss

Answer (score 0):

It's an nvme drive, you probably need to install nvme-cli to check the APM settings, and the reason that ioctl didn't work.  The z_wr_iss threads are ZFS on Linux's write threads.  Those buffered reads are very slow, maybe the memory on your system is slow?  Or perhaps it could be a ZFS tuning issue.